# How do I utilize text in a string as a method?

Tags: java, string, function

Say I want my user to type a command into a string:

```
String command = scan.nextLine();
```

And they type something like `object.function()`. How could I call the function they typed?

Comment: Do you want them to be able to call any arbitrary function (as if they're entering code that's compiled and run?), or only ones from a pre-specified list? If the latter,

Comment: @Kitsune Code from a pre-specified list, like a class's method.

Answer (score 2):

Use **Reflection** to find and invoke the method on a particular object by name.

This will help you out:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

Something similar to this:

```
Class c = Class.forName("targetName");
Object o = c.newInstance();

OR

c = myExistingObj.getClass();

Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getSomething");
m.invoke(o, <params>);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the function exists somewhere in your code then use this:

```
ActivateUserDefAction.class.getMethod("method", null).invoke(this, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [Janino as a script evaluator](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Basic), which can compile, load and run Java code on the fly.

Answer (score -1):

I would use an if else statement or (ick) a switch case statement. Since java is compiled you can't just write code and have java execute it.

For example:

```
Object duck = new Object();
String userInput = System.in.read();
if (userInput = "duck.quack();"){
//do something
duck.quack();
}
else if (userInput = "duck.fly();"){
//do something else
duck.fly();
}
//etc.
```

- Edited to add a code example

Comment: Not actually true, via a number of mechanisms.

Comment: @Muricula See [`JavaCompiler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) and [`Runtime.exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) / [`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html).

Comment: @Muricula This is not true, and he's not looking for a shell exec or a class loader. You can identify and call a method by name through Reflection.